# How to explain the action of putting a table calendar facedown from an upright position?

Tags: terminology

I am unable to come up with the words to explain this action. To turn it the other away would still mean it is in an upright position. Put it down does not sound right either. Please help.

Comment: Upside down ? (Like in the song)

Comment: Do you mean put it down face first on the table?

Comment: @AMACB Yes. But how can I express that it is done with some extent of physical force to suggest frustration? Putting it down face first can be read as a passive action.

Comment: He "slammed the calendar face-down onto the table in frustration."

Answer (score 3):

All valid:

- "He put/laid/turned/knocked/pushed the calendar face down" (obviously)
- "He put/laid/turned/knocked/pushed the calendar on its face"
- "He pushed/knocked/flicked/smacked the calendar over" ("He turned the calendar over" would imply putting it upside down, but these don't)

Comment: I'd say "laid the calendar face down", unless a more violent action needed to be indicated.

Answer (score 0):

'He flattened the calendar to the table'.

Example 'John turned, and flattening the calendar to the table, turned to Kathleen. Looking into her shining eyes, he said quietly 'Kathleen, whatever the dates are - it doesn't matter. We're going to bring up this baby, and do it together, don't you worry...'

If you want more urgency you could use 'smashed', like this:

Example 'John smashed the calendar to the table with a bang, turning to Kathleen with flashing eyes. Kathleen! I won't hear this again! It's our baby and we're keeping it!'